# best way to generate wsdl in php for java axis client

Tags: php, web-services, wsdl, apache-axis, webservice-client

I am consuming a web service written in PHP. I am using axis to generate client jar on my side but when i generate client code from WSDL and make request, request xml contains multiRef tag and the php server can not understand this tag. I will ask them to generate a wsdl in a new way. I searched and there are many ways in php to create wsdl. Which method is the best way for the clients using axis? Have you experienced such a problem before? if yes what did you do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service was rpc-encoded, i ask them to change it to rpc-literal and the problem is solved.